# Добавление индексов в SphinxSearch или ManticoreSearch в runtime-режиме

Tags: sphinxsearch, manticoresearch

Мы решили использовать sphinxsearch не для поиска, а для ускорения отображения информации пользователю. Мы хотели сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь добавлял новую запись, она мгновенно появлялась бы на экране в списке имеющихся. Для обновления индексов мы внутри нашего модуля вызываем indexer для соответствующего индекса. Однако оказалось, что если запустить несколько переиндексаций одного и того же индекса одновременно, то выполнится только первая, а остальные отвалятся из-за блокировки временного файла, в котором и происходит переиндексация. Есть ли в SphinxSearch или ManticoreSearch какой-нибудь другой способ переиндексации, который может подойти для нашей цели? Мы пробовали разобраться с RT-индексами, но пока не поняли их суть.

Comment: Разбирайтесь с RT-индексами, непонятно что вы не поняли